# This regex to include zero

Tags: regex

I have this regex, which does what expected fine.

```
^([\d]{3,6})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Now I have requirement for this to be changed to also matches on zero without or with 1 or 2 decimal places..

This is what I have so far

```
^([\d]{3,6})(\.\d{1,2})|[0]{1}(\.\d{1,2})
```

which almost works, but it won't accept the whole numbers without decimal points..

Anyone knows how to make it so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d{2,5})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: But strangely your accepted answer is pretty long regex for the same job.

Comment: To be honest it is NOT about gaining a 15 point rep. Think of some other person visiting your question later and look at the accepted answer thinking that is indeed the right way to do it. I won't mind if Julien takes my regex and edits his/her answer with this regex.

Comment: Thanks for giving it to me in the first place but @anubhava is right, the best answer should be the one accepted. If you really want to give me rep points, feel free to upvote my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have removed the question mark from your original regex:

```
^([\d]{3,6})(\.\d{1,2})?|[0]{1}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```